# I am a 9 letter word. Who am I riddle

Tags: riddle

I am a 9 letter word. 
6,5,4,9 = generally found in books 
8,2,3,4 = An ornament 
4,8,5,6,9,1 = A fruit

https://brainyyou.com/i-am-a-9-letter-word-who-am-i-guess-the-word/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The word is

> Singapore

Taking letters from this word corresponding to the numbers shown gives:

> 6, 5, 4, 9 = "Page". Found in books. 
>  8, 2, 3, 4 = "Ring". Ornament you wear. 
>  4, 8, 5, 6, 9, 1 = "Grapes". Fruit